# How to configure postfix and dovecot so that thunderbird can automatically find settings

Tags: postfix, configuration, dovecot, thunderbird, autoconfiguration

Our mailserver is a Ubuntu Server box with a Postfix/Dovecot combination. We enabled starttls with a correct certificate and everything is working ok.

A lot of our users are using Thunderbird for retrieving mail with IMAP. Thunderbird tries to guess the configuration of our server (or autodetect it), but that always fails, resulting in that our users need to give the settings manually.

What are the steps we should take to 'help' thunderbird and enabling auto-configuration?

Answer (score 4):

Thunderbird autoconfig is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Thunderbird/Autoconfiguration)

You may want to use a tool like [automx](http://www.automx.org/en/) though which supports auto-configs for other mail clients as well.

Answer (score 2):

Basically You have to serve a simple **configuration XML** file on the `autoconfig.example.com/mail/config-v1.1.xml` address, described on this page:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Autoconfiguration/FileFormat/HowTo